# Why can't I set a variable based on result of expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following line of code, with a debugger call:

```
usr_has_widget = usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name)
debugger
```

My app stops in debug mode and I get the following:

```
(rdb:11) usr_has_widget
false
(rdb:11) usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name)
true
```

So the right hand expression is resolving to 'true' but the variable `usr_has_widget` is being set to 'false'. Why does `usr_has_widget` not get set to 'true'?

Comment: If you are using libraries/tools that are not part of standard Ruby, then put that in the tag or write about that.

Comment: We can't help you much unless we know what string `wlist` is returning, but, offhand, I'd say that `'\;'` isn't what you want to search for. More likely you want to search for `';'`.

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way, did you go to the debugger before or after the statement in question?

Comment: On top of what the Tin Man wrote, replacing something into `','` and then splitting with the same `","` is not clever.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one thing called `usr_has_widget` e.g. a method with same name as the variable?

Comment: I have a list like "doweighin;domeasurements,weightplot" - contents vary but are essentially 2 comma delimited lists separated by a ; & I want to split the whole thing & test for existence of a given element, eg doweighin. But, either way - the expression evaluates to true but the variable gets set to false - that's what I dont understand

Comment: sawa - what bits do you mean 'not part of standard Ruby'? if you mean 'debugger' thats just the standard rails debugger

Comment: Peter Alfvin it jumps to debugger as shown after evaluating the line above it. Neil Slater - no other useage of usr_has_widget

Comment: It is difficult to make this question any more simple than the 6 lines above but I'll try. If I make a debugger call AFTER a line of code which is thus: a = b, then WITHIN debugger AT THAT POINT if 'b' is evaluating to 'true' then 'a' must also evaluate to 'true', because 'a' has just been set to the vale of 'b', which debugger is showing as 'true'. In my code, this is not happening. The question, again, is: why does usr_has_widget get set to 'false' when debugger clearly shows usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name) as being 'true'?

Comment: Actually a simpler way to describe the questions is: Rails runtime code is evaluating the expression usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name) as 'false' whereas Rails debugger (ruby-debug19) is evaluating it as 'true'. Why is this?

Comment: Finally.. there is an inconsistency with ruby-debug19 as follows: If I have a string, lst = "a,b,c;d,e,f" then within the debugger typing the expression lst.gsub('\;', ',') returns "a,b,c,d,e,f" whereas it seems that when the Rails code runs without the debugger call, it doesn't sub the ; and returns "a,b,c;d,e,f". This is actually the answer - debugger will show lst.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?("c") as true, Rails code says it's false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the Ruby debugger (I'm using ruby-debug19 with Rails 3.2.11), which doesn't seem to like semi-colons in strings (throws an unterminated string meets end of file error).

Thus in my line above

```
usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name)
```

the Ruby interpreter will look for a literal backslash followed by a semi-colon and in my case not find a match and then not apply the split that follows it, thus returning a 'false' value (if the widget I'm looking for is either side of the semi-colon)

Dropping into the debugger, however, you MUST apply the backslash to avoid the error, the debugger ignores the backslash, applies the substitution and the following split works - thus returning a 'true' result

Thus you get the opposite boolean result depending on whether you are in ruby debug mode or the code is running under the interpreter - making it very confusing to debug!

[This SO answer describes the debugger in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063340/ruby-on-rails-a-string-with-a-semicolon-results-in-unterminated-string-meets-e)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things to think about.

Starting with:

```
str = "doweighin;domeasurements,weightplot"
str.gsub(';', ',').split(',') # => ["doweighin", "domeasurements", "weightplot"]
str.gsub(';', ',').split(',').include?('weightplot') # => true
```

Using `.gsub(';', ',').split(',')` is silly though, when `split` lets us use a regular expression:

```
str.split(/[;,]/) # => ["doweighin", "domeasurements", "weightplot"]
```

There is a small problem in that the search will fail if the case of either the target or search words are different:

```
str.split(/[;,]/).include?('WeightPlot') # => false
```

You can fix that by folding the case to either upper or lower-case before doing the test:

```
str.downcase.split(/[;,]/).include?('WeightPlot'.downcase) # => true
```

There are shorter ways to do the test though:

```
str['weightplot'] # => "weightplot"
```

Which simply does an in-string search. This can return a false-positive if the string you're looking for is found inside another string.

```
str[/\bWeightPlot\b/i] # => "weightplot"
```

Which uses a regex to look for the word, ignoring cases, and requires there be word-boundaries on either side of it.

Rather than hard-code the target string though, use string interpolation to insert it at run-time:

```
target = 'WeightPlot'
str[/\b#{ target }\b/i] # => "weightplot"
```

You can turn the result of the short-cuts into boolean true/false using `!!`. A "not-not" is a nice way to turn `nil` results into false and anything else into true:

```
!!str['weightplot'] # => true
!!str[/\bWeightPlot\b/i] # => true
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed reply. You are correct in that my gsub('\;', ',') is incorrect, and also that there are better ways of doing this. However, the problem looks like a ruby-debug19 issue. At the debug point, it evaluates the line usr_wid_list.wlist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(widget.widget_name) as true (as I show in my question), but outside of debug, the code seems to evaluate it as false - hence my confusion. Not sure how to mark this up in SO?